# Ruby on Rails : Background CSS Image from Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, background-image, activeadmin, carrierwave

I want to create a picture management through my ActiveAdmin administration panel.

I use Carrierwave to upload images from my administration panel, however I fail to display these images as background-image within my CSS code... :/

...because of the following error:

```
couldn't find file '<%= Image.find(1).path %>'
```

[image: error screenshot]

Here is my CSS:

```
header{
   background-image: asset-data-url("<%= Image.find(1).path %>");
}
```

My HTML:

```
<header>
<div class="header-content">
    <div class="header-content-inner">
        <h1>Your Favorite Source of Free Bootstrap Themes</h1>
        <hr>
        <p>Start Bootstrap can help you build better websites using the Bootstrap CSS framework! Just download your template and start going, no strings attached!</p>
        <a href="#about" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll">Find Out More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the image administration view:

[image: view screenshot]

I don't understand how do I link my image to the background-image CSS property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling Rails Database queries in CSS stylesheet will not work. Instead you can rework on the HTML code like the below,

```
<header style="background-image: url(<%= Image.find(1).path %>);">
```

and remove the background image code in the CSS.

Comment: Hello Shabini,

Thank you for your answer.

I try that way and there is no error but the image is not displayed :(

Comment: `image_tag` shouldn't come here. @EmilienLecoffre, Try removing `image_tag` from the code.